# Find only instances of domain name without www with a regex

Tags: regex, vim

In a large text file (actually a database dump), I need to find *only* those occurrences of a domain name that do NOT have www.

So, I DO want to find (for example):

```
http://example.com

/example.com

example.com
```

But I Do NOT want to find:

```
www.example.com
http://www.example.com
/www.example.com
```

I'm thinking of using vim ... though I am open to other ideas. But I haven't been able to figure out a regex to do it.

(BTW, the overall issue can't be fixed any other way (e.g. .htaccess) ... long story.)

Comment: You can open the file with vim and use `:g/www\./d` to remove all lines containing `www.`

Comment: I don't think that this should be closed. This is a task that someone could just as well need to do in a program. It's not the only question here regarding regexes.

Answer (score 2):

I dont know if VIM supports this but try:

```
(?<!www\.)example.com
```

with a bit of search I found that can be like this in vim:

```
/\(www\.\)\@<!example\.com
```

Comment: Thanks Darka - I tried this, but it doesn't seem to match anything.